# Remove gaps between subplots_mosaic in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

How do I remove the gaps between the subplots on a mosaic? The traditional way does not work with mosaics:

```
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
```

I also tried using `gridspec_kw`, but no luck.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ax = plt.figure(layout="constrained").subplot_mosaic(
    """
    abcde
    fghiX
    jklXX
    mnXXX
    oXXXX
    """,
    empty_sentinel="X",
    gridspec_kw={
        "wspace": 0,
        "hspace": 0,
    },
)


for k,ax in ax.items():
    print(ax)
    #ax.text(0.5, 0.5, k, transform=ax.transAxes, ha="center", va="center", fontsize=8, color="darkgrey")
    ax.set_xticklabels([])
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
    ax.tick_params(length = 0)
```

The code generates:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not caused by `subplot_mosaic` but because a `layout` was specified. If you use constrained or tight layout, the layout manager will supersede the custom adjustments.

Remove the layout manager and either method will work:

[image]

- `gridspec_kw`

  ```
  fig = plt.figure() # without layout param
  ax = fig.subplot_mosaic(
      """
      abcde
      fghiX
      jklXX
      mnXXX
      oXXXX
      """,
      empty_sentinel="X",
      gridspec_kw={
          "wspace": 0,
          "hspace": 0,
      },
  )
  ```
- `subplots_adjust`

  ```
  fig = plt.figure() # without layout param
  ax = fig.subplot_mosaic(
      """
      abcde
      fghiX
      jklXX
      mnXXX
      oXXXX
      """,
      empty_sentinel="X",
  )
  fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
  ```